# Doctrine Extensions

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I create doctrine extension called **DATESTRING**, but i got error.

```
  "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%M ))"
```

**MonthStringFunction.php**

```
    use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser;

    /**
     * "MONTHSTRING" "(" SimpleArithmeticExpression ")"
     *
     * @category    DoctrineExtensions
     */
    class MonthStringFunction extends FunctionNode
    {
        public $date;

        /**
         * @override
         */
        public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
        {
            return "MONTHSTRING(DATE_FORMAT(" . $sqlWalker->walkArithmeticPrimary($this->date) . ", %M ))"; //**here some error**
        }

        /**
         * @override
         */
        public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
        {
            $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
            $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);

            $this->date = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();

            $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
        }
    }
```

**TestRepository.php**

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('tst');
    $qb->select('MONTHSTRING(tst.joinDate) as month_string');
    $data = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
    return $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

The format argument of `DATE_FORMAT` function needs to be enclosed by quotes, because it is a string. Try this:

```
public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
{
    return "MONTHSTRING(DATE_FORMAT(" . $sqlWalker->walkArithmeticPrimary($this->date) . ", '%M' ))"; //**here some error**
}
```

Comment: Used that, get error "Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION demo.MONTHSTRING does not exist"

Comment: Did you register your custom function to Doctrine 2?

Comment: I think you wanted to do it like this:
`return "DATE_FORMAT(" . $sqlWalker->walkArithmeticPrimary($this->date) . ", '%M' )";`